# How to delete tail grep matches?

Tags: grep, tail

I have checked out previous posts but could not find anything that worked for me. I have a log file that has been made huge by some recurring error that was a result of changes I made to a script. I want to delete all lines containing this error message.

When I run

```
sudo tail -1000000 /var/log/kannel/MT.usage.log|grep 'utf-8'
```

I display from the log file all entries that look like

```
...[22297] [3] ERROR: Failed to convert string from <utf-8> to <UTF-16BE>, errno was <84>
```

There are more than 1 million lines. I want to delete all these entries from the log file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
sed -i '/ERROR: Failed to convert string from to/d' filename.log
```